# I have problem with deploying Sanity studio on Netlify

Tags: netlify, sanity

it maybe silly questions to someone here but I have nowhere to ask so I came here.
I deployed my portfolio page with Sanity & Gatsby Starter.
It works okay → https://lovethis.one.
[deploy status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZY2i5.png)
The website is deployed perfectly but Studio keeps failing when I try to deploy.

On netlify it says it's failing because

```
$ npm run build-studio && cp studio/netlify.toml studio/dist
12:52:01 AM: > sanity-gatsby-portfolio@0.0.0 build-studio
12:52:01 AM: > (cd studio && npm run build)
12:52:01 AM: > sanity-gatsby-portfolio-studio@1.0.6 build
12:52:01 AM: > sanity build
12:52:01 AM: sh: 1: sanity: not found
12:52:01 AM: ​
12:52:01 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
12:52:01 AM:   "build.command" failed                                        
12:52:01 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
12:52:01 AM: ​
12:52:01 AM:   Error message
12:52:01 AM:   Command failed with exit code 127: npm run build-studio && cp studio/netlify.toml studio/dist
12:52:01 AM: ​
12:52:01 AM:   Error location
12:52:01 AM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
12:52:01 AM:   npm run build-studio && cp studio/netlify.toml studio/dist
12:52:01 AM: ​
12:52:01 AM:   Resolved config
12:52:01 AM:   build:
12:52:01 AM:     base: /opt/build/repo
12:52:01 AM:     command: npm run build-studio && cp studio/netlify.toml studio/dist
12:52:01 AM:     commandOrigin: ui
12:52:01 AM:     environment:
12:52:01 AM:       - INCOMING_HOOK_BODY
12:52:01 AM:       - INCOMING_HOOK_TITLE
12:52:01 AM:       - INCOMING_HOOK_URL
12:52:01 AM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/studio/dist
12:52:01 AM:     publishOrigin: ui
```

I am quite newbie here and hope I can find answer.
Also I am wondering why my studio shows the blank area like this.
[blank area on dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bG4XP.png)
On the content side, it the name of the project is sample project I also wish to change.
[sample project not project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3ioA.png)
Thank you in advance for your help!
If I broke any rules here, I will try to edit or fix the content.
Thank you for understanding.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Sanity CLI isn't installed so when the script tries to run the `sanity build` command, it fails. Could you run `npm install @sanity/cli` (note—not globally) in your studio folder, then try pushing/deploying once again?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! It seems not working but I will try other options. Have a lovely day!